# firestore search query for sub-map [in JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how to search a document where members map contains a particular `map_id`

```
chatRoom: {
MVyMPi78DOwVQ5w5GnYe: {
      ...
      members: {
         <member_1_id>: {
            id: xxxxx,
            unreadmessagecount: xx
         },
         <member_2_id>: {
            id: xxxxx,
            unreadmessagecount: xx
         }
     },
La234Pi78DOwVQ5w5GnYe: {
      ...
      members: {
         <member_1_id>: {
            id: xxxxx,
            unreadmessagecount: xx
         },
         <member_2_id>: {
            id: xxxxx,
            unreadmessagecount: xx
         }
       }
}
```

like for above structure get all chatrooms where `members` `map` contains `member_id` assume `member_id` is known
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *dot notation* to query documents based on nested field as shown below:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'chatRoom'), where('members.user1', '==', {<obj>}))
```

This won't work for your use-case unless you know the exact object i.e. `{ uid: 'user1', unreadMessageCount: 1 }`.

As a workaround, you can use `orderBy()` clause that'll only return documents where the field exists like this:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'chatRoom'), orderBy('members.user1'))
```

However, this is actually querying the whole collection and so writing security rules will be a bit difficult. For example, if you use `allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members`, the rule will fail as there will be many documents where this returns false.

---

I would recommend using storing all members' UIDs in an array as follows:

```
{
  ...
  group: false,
  memberIds: ['user_1_uid', 'user_3_uid']
}
```

Then you can use [`array-contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) operator to query all chat rooms of a user like this:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'chatRoom'), where('memberIds', 'array-contains', 'some_uid'))
```

Then you can use the following security rules to ensure only a chat member can read/write the document:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.memberIds
```

Comment: initially I am using the last one, which you recommended, a members array, but also have to store the unread message count for each member that's why i choose map

Comment: @MohammadDanish that'll be `group Ascending`,  `members.user1.uid Ascending` and  `recentMessage.sendAt Descending`. As you can see, you'll have to create a composite index for every user ID that is not feasible. Firestore also supports up to 200 composite indexes. Dynamic fields names (i.e. using UIDs) will just keep increasing number of indexes that Firestore creates automatically so it might be best to use an array.

Comment: i also think so. and now I think it is better to create a very new collection for Notifications which has all related data for unread messages and notifications for each user and for every chatroom

Comment: @MohammadDanish where are messages stored? Firestore has a new [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) query. You can maybe store a field `read: true/false` in message document and get count of messages where read is false.

Comment: in a seperate collection. so for each message sent/received, i have to update the count, there is one more technique like ```members: [currentUser.uid, user.uid],unseenMessageCount: {
          [currentUser.uid]: 0,
          [user.uid]: 0,
        },``` in this way, each time a message is sent, count is updated and also didnt need to create index for each members

Comment: @MohammadDanish that's what I mentioned in my answer, to store the members UIDs in a different array irrespective of where the count is coming from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249032/discussion-between-mohammad-danish-and-dharmaraj).